# I extruded a face before i aplied a subdivision surface can i still make a face between vertices?

Tags: modeling, vertices, subdivision-surface, extrude

I hope the title didnt confuse you its a bit hard to explain since im new and dont know everything yet.

So let me explain in a bit more detail.
Im trying to make a lipton ice tea glass in blender.

I started with placing a cylinder and made it into the bowl/top of the glass(check the pics for a more clear understanding). I deleted the top face so its a open cup.
I then added a solidify and a subdivision surface but didnt apply them yet.

Now here is where it went wrong i extruded the bottom of that glass to make the trunk/beam (which goes to the feet).
But the top and bottom of that beam are open. When i select all vertices on that line and fill it in by hitting F it makes a plane but it isnt connected to the glass because of the subdivision surface.

Im sorry i find it a bit difficult to explain hopefully my pictures are understandable. At the end all i want is to close the hole in the bottom of my glass so it wont spill fluid.

[image: My Model]
this is my model

[image: The hole top side]
Here you see the hole from the top

[image: Bottom hole]
the botom of the beam

[image: The vertices filled with F]
Here you see the vertices i filled in by pressing F. As you can see it doesnt make any contact to the actual glas. This is the topview/inside the glass

Answer (score 1):

So long as modifiers are unapplied, you can "deactivate" their influence in the preview by clicking the Viewport Preview button in the modifier settings. This can be very handy, as it lets you see the mesh without the modifiers (which can make some faces/edges/vertices hard to see with the modifier(s) on - also things like the Solidify Modifier make it seem as if there are faces where there are none (until it is applied)).

[image: ModButton]

Comment: I just re-read your question - It is also possible that the problem you're having is because you're trying to add a face in the "middle" of an interior. Faces in Blender have a direction, and generally blender is good at knowing which are facing "inside" and which are facing "outside". However, if you add a (bi-directional) face in the middle of (perpendicular to) an "interior" corridor, blender gets confused as to what is interior and what is exterior any more (because the face you added has both and "inward" and an "outward" face). If this is the case, you will need to alter your topology.

Comment: Im still a newbie to blender so im not getting everything but it was a solid vertex/plane but when i extruded it it vanished. Im following the blenderguru donut tutorial and he  applied the subdiv and solidify before he made an extrusion. and i didnt. So it was bassically the in and outside allready. all i did was extrude. And the face should only have a top or botom side since the beam should be solid. i guess if i delete the subdiv add a face and add the subdiv it might help. w8 a sec

Comment: If you want my honest advice - and I've given this before because I deeply believe in it - when doing the donut tutorial, _everytime_ you make a mistake, close the file, start fresh and do it all again from the beginning. The repetition will make you way more comfortable with the keyboard shortcuts, and will help you memorize the method. Also, you will often find you missed things that Andrew said the first (or second, or third, etc..) time around. I know it sounds like a cop-out, but trust me, it works. You'll be able to get your "creation time" down to 4 minutes start-to-finish by the end.

Comment: yeah thats true i used to learn english(im dutch) this way we where given 50 words and everytime i didnt know 1 i started all over from the beginning. it worked since i was probably the highest scoring in english from my class 9,7/10.  But my grammar aint there.

Answer (score 0):

@CristhopherBennet i think i fixed it after reading your answer i decided to do what i commented on your answer. i deleted those 2 modifiers added/filled in the vetices with F and added those modifiers again and  [image]
[image]
now it looks like this. its connected now i just have to makeup it a bit to remove those rinkles it seems to have worked. Thank you for your comment and time.

Comment: To remove the "wrinkles", inset the bottom face. The reason this is happening is because the bottom face is an n-gon (face with more than 4 vertices). Blender prefers quads (exactly 4 vertices per face), especially for shading, and _very especially_ around curved, smoothed surfaces. You can often get away with n-gons, however, so long as they're in the middle of a flat face, which is why insetting the bottom face will fix your problem.

Comment: And for the record, your English is practically flawless, and your grammar is no worse than the majority of people (including native english speakers) on the "internet". Proost!